# Convert audio-track-id from an m3u playlist to ffmpeg stream id

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, playlists

I have an m3u playlist with the following format:

```
...
#EXTINF:0,10115 - Only Rai
#EXTVLCOPT:ts-es-id-pid
#EXTVLCOPT:no-video
#EXTVLCOPT:audio-track-id=1008
rtsp://mafreebox.freebox.fr/fbxtv_pub/stream?namespace=1&service=100015
#EXTINF:0,10118 - Corail la webradio
#EXTVLCOPT:ts-es-id-pid
#EXTVLCOPT:no-video
#EXTVLCOPT:audio-track-id=1009
rtsp://mafreebox.freebox.fr/fbxtv_pub/stream?namespace=1&service=100015
```

Both programs share the same URL. I'm trying to figure out the stream number in ffmpeg according to the audio-track-id property (so that i can use the -map switch to select a specific stream).

I found nothing about this in ffmpeg doc.

Thanks

PS: here 's the output

```
ffmpeg version 1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers built on Jan 10 2013 14:51:35 with Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/1.1 --enable-shared --enable-gpl -enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --cc=cc --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
libavutil      52. 13.100 / 52. 13.100
libavcodec     54. 86.100 / 54. 86.100
libavformat    54. 59.106 / 54. 59.106
libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
libavfilter     3. 32.100 /  3. 32.100
libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
http://mafreebox.freebox.fr/freeboxtv/playlist.m3u: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I don't see why ffmpeg would process playlist directly

Comment: ffmpeg does process m3u8 directly, but maybe only the HLS ones. Why do you have rtsp stream in it?

Comment: I thought it would process it only for output. The playlist I have is provided by my ISP box, these are radio streams

Answer (score 1):

What do you get when you `ffprobe file.m3u8` ? This should return the stream numbers for you to map.

Comment: Nothing: it's not a recognized file format by ffmpeg

Comment: @xol Are you using ancient ffmpeg or something recent? Show your complete console output.